# Как считать определенное количество компонентов из файла

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

Решил такую задачу

> Дан файл f, компоненты которого являются целыми числами. Записать в файл g наибольшее значение первых ста компонент файла f, затем - следующих ста компонент и т.д. Если в последней группе окажется менее 
>   ста компонент, то последняя компонента файла g должна быть равна наибольшей из компонент файла f, образующих последнюю (неполную) группу.

Код

```
String^ str;
        String^str1;
        StreamWriter^ wr1 = File::CreateText("f.txt");

        //int f = 0;


    private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
        wr1->Close();

        StreamWriter^ wr = File::CreateText("g.txt");//     Создаем файл
        int cnt = 0, max = 0, v;

        StreamReader ^rd = File::OpenText("f.txt");
        while (true)
        {

            str = rd->ReadLine();
            // Или в конце или каждые 100 элементов пишем результат
            if ((str == nullptr) || (cnt >= 100))
            {
                wr->WriteLine(max);
                cnt = 0;
                //Читаем, пока не достигнем конца или 100 строч. Пишем в файл результат.
                if (str == nullptr)
                    break;//Если конец - выйти из цикла.
            }
                v = Convert::ToInt32(str);
            if ((cnt == 0) || (v > max))
                max = v;//В конце цикла ищем среди чисел максимум
            textBox3->Text = Convert::ToString(max);

            cnt++;
        }
        wr->Close();

        rd->Close();

    }

    private: System::Void MyForm_Load(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    }
    bool msg;
    private: System::Void button2_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
        //ЗАПИСЬ                                                          //1.нажимается кнопка
                                                                          //число из текстбокс1  записывается в файл f
                                                                          //очищение текстбокс1
        bool msg;
        wr1->Close();
        StreamWriter^ wr2 = File::AppendText("f.txt");
        try {
            Convert::ToInt32(textBox1->Text);

        }

        catch (...)
        {
            MessageBox::Show("Не жульничайте, введите число!!");
            msg = true;
        }
        if (msg != true) {

            wr2->WriteLine(textBox1->Text);
            wr2->Close();
            //str[f] = Convert::ToInt32(textBox1->Text + "\n");
            str1 += textBox1->Text;
            textBox2->Text = str1;
            //f+=1;
            textBox1->Text = " ";
            msg = false;
        }
        wr2->Close();
    }
```

Тут идет под отдельную кнопку запись числа в файл с клавиатуры,
Далее как раз идет считывание с этого файла.
Меня интересует эта строчка

```
str = rd->ReadLine();
```

Я считаю, что добавление в переменную при огромном количестве чисел будет не самым хорошим решением

*Вопрос* :
Возможно ли ее переписать так , чтобы не считывался весь файл в раз, а по 100 компонентов, как написано в условии?(Загрузили 100 элементов - обработали, написали наибольшее значение,загрузили следующие 100. Если меньше 100 элементов - загрузили все элементы и написали наибольшее значение)

P.s : Просьба не писать про плохой код и "мои глазааа", я прекрасно это знаю, просто хочу получить ответ на вопрос.

Comment: Зачем вы открываете файловый поток: `StreamWriter^ wr1 = File::CreateText("f.txt");` в полях формы, а затем в методе сразу же его закрываете: `wr1->Close();` Смысл этого действия?

Comment: Дело в том, что эта кнопка выполняется не первой, а если я не буду закрывать, то я не смогу открыть другие потоки и возникают ошибки, я пробовал по разному, остановился на этом

Comment: Посмотрите описание методов `File.CreateText`, `File.AppendText` - они сами создают файл, если его не существует (а если существует, то открывают). Поэтому не нужно предварительно им "помогать", создавая файл.

Comment: Хорошо , я посмотрю, но давай-те вернемся к самому вопросу..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Код на C#. Думаю, не составит труда перевести его на C++/CLI.

Создадим тестовый файл со случайно сгенерированными данными:

```
var rand = new Random();
using (var writer = new StreamWriter("f.txt"))
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 250; i++)
    {
        writer.WriteLine(rand.Next());
    }
}
```

На каждой строке по одному числу.

Код чтения по одной строке и вычисления наибольшего значения из ста:

```
try
{
    using (var reader = File.OpenText("f.txt"))
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter("g.txt"))
    {
        string str = null;
        int counter = 0;
        int max = int.MinValue;

        while ((str = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            int number = int.Parse(str);
            max = Math.Max(number, max);
            counter++;
            if (counter == 100)
            {                                
                writer.WriteLine(max);
                counter = 0;
                max = int.MinValue;
            }
        }
        if (counter != 0)
        {                            
            writer.WriteLine(max);
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e);
}
```

Последнее условие `if` необходимо для обработки случая меньше ста компонент в конце файла.

---

Неоднократно уже говорил и повторю ещё раз: язык C++/CLI не предназначен для прикладной разработки. Единственное его предназначение - выступать в качестве "клея" между *управляемым* (C#) и *неуправляемым* (C++) кодом.

Посмотрите, как легко и изящно решается проблема разбиения на блоки необходимого размера в языке C# с помощью технологии LINQ и пакета MoreLinq:

```
var batches = File.ReadLines("f.txt").Select(int.Parse).Batch(100);

foreach (var batch in batches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(batch.Max());
}
```

Переходите на светлую сторону!

Comment: Мне интересует как работают между собой и что делают  эти строки
string str = null;

и

while ((str = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
в чем магия null в с#?

Comment: @propane67 - [StreamReader.ReadLine](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.readline?view=netframework-4.8). Пока в файле что-то есть, этот метод возвращает очередную строку. Как только файл становится пуст, этот метод возвращает `null`.

Comment: Ок, но столкнулся с проблемкой, не могу присвоить строковой переменной null из-за различия типов.
String^ str = NULL;
как можно исправить?

Comment: @propane67 - ну вы же в своем коде используете именно этот метод. `nullptr`

Comment: Момент, который я сейчас не понимаю, почему если не присваивать `str = reader.ReadLine())`,а писать просто `reader.ReadLine())`  то будет выводиться 0?

Comment: @propane67 - не задавайте вопросы в комментариях. Создайте новую тему с вопросом. PS: Прочитанную строку нужно использовать дальше по коду. Если не делать присвоение, тогда зачем вообще читать?